# Space navy book, possibly a series, read between 2015 and 2020

Tags: story-identification

Once again this is one of those queries where I only recall a scene from the book.

I read it within the last six years, in the UK from a library, I can't think of the cover.

It had a somewhat Honor Harrington feel, in as much as all the space battles were human Vs human and very little mention of Earth, instead there were various star system empires.

The only thing I still remember is one of the officers had to meet his Emperor/King and traditional protocol demands he is suitably prepared beforehand.

The flunkies basically stick a wig on him, carefully make up his face with lots of cosmetics and put him in a very fancy uniform.

Then, so he doesn't crease his clothing by walking and thus spoil the effect, they mount him on a Hannibal Lector style luggage trolley and wheel him in for the royal audience - he's done all this before so he bears it with fortitude.

I've went through the checklists to no avail

Comment: You've read it recently, but how old did it seem to be?

Comment: It seemed up to date....like 2010 (ish) to 2020